# Javascript event for text selection from non editable elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is any event is available in javascript for select text from non editable element like div or span.
I want to do selected text from paragraph and highlight text from opening popup color box on page.
I am opening color box by ending of text selection by user. So how can i catch event when user end text selection.
I tried with mouse up event Like:

```
var slideElement = angular.element('.myElement', elem);
slideElement.bind('mouseup', (event) => {
  // Funtionality goes here
)};
```

It will work fine for desktop but on touch devices it will not work. So can i handle selection end event in proper way so that it work fine for both desktop and touch devices.
Touch end event will also not work when we are selecting a text from touch device.
 Thanks

Comment: Have you tried touchmove event ? @Gitesh Pubia

Comment: @MuhammedNeswine touchmove also not work when we selecting text. I want text selection events.

Answer (score 0):

The best browser compatible code for selecting text from a `div` or a `span` on the handler of an event is the following:

```js
function SelectText(element) {
  var doc = document,
    text = doc.getElementById(element),
    range, selection;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'click') {
    SelectText('selectme');
  }
};
```

```css
.click {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectme">
  <p>Some text goes here!</p>
  <p>More text!</p>
</div>
<p class="click">Click me!</p>
```

This should work well on a mobile device too.